# Paraphrasing an statements

Tags: paraphrasing

I would like to paraphrase the following statements

```
  They have little social experience beyound its boundaries 

  The influence of the peer group climaxes in adolescence
```

Could you please help me

The context for first statement is :

The family is where children establish their first close emotional ties, learn language, and begin to internalize cultutral norms and values. To young children the family is all-encompassing. They have little social experience beyond its boundaries and therefore lack any basis for comparing and evaluating what is learnt from family members.

For second one :

The influence of the peer group climaxes in adolescence, when young people are apt to form a distinctive subculture with its own tastes, dress, jargon, symbols, values and heroes .

Answer (score 1):

Trying to paraphrase the first sentence is difficult. Who are "they"? What is the "it" with boundaries? Without more context, about all you can do is is rearrange the same words to say something like "Socially, their experience lies almost exclusively within its boundaries." That is still amazingly vague (though in context it may be much more meaningful).

The second sentence provides a wealth of opportunities for paraphrase.

"No cohort is more influenced by peer groups than adolescents."

"Peer groups influence adolescents more than any other age group."

"Adolescence is when the influence of the peer group peaks."

"Adolescents are those most influenced by their peers."

It is easy to find multiple ways to express the thought because the original statement is clear albeit a bit stilted for my taste.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is ambiguous since "**its**" is not understood, but [possibly this might work:

> They have little social experience beyound **its** boundaries.
>   They have little social experience *with the wider world*.

In your second example, "**peaks**" may be a better choice than "**climax**" which may have more sexual connotations.

> The influence of the peer group *climaxes* in adolescence.
>   Peer group influence *peaks* during adolescence.